# Tellus' "briny robes"

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, word-choice, ancient-greek

I read in Keats' [Hyperion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_(poem)):

> [...] No, by Tellus and her briny robes!
>
> (Hyperion, 246)

[Tellus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_(mythology)) is a Latin goddess, her Greek counterpart being [Gaia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia).

I am looking for the Greek or Latin source of the words "briny robes". Does an author like Hesiod or Homer (or even Ovid) refer to this expression?

Comment: If there is no attested phrase that Keats was referencing, would you be interested in a translation of this anyway?

Comment: @Adam : why not ? A translation into Greek or Latin might help me to find the original expression more quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Greek word that means *briny* is [ἁλμυρός](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%28lmuro%5Cn&la=greek&can=a%28lmuro%5Cn0&prior=pi/en&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0135:book=4:card=481&i=1#lexicon) and appears in both Homer and Hesiod. For example:

> Grant lovely song and celebrate the holy race of the deathless gods
> who are for ever, those that were born of Earth and starry Heaven and
> gloomy Night and them that briny Sea did rear. (Hesiod, *[Theogony](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0020,001:132&lang=original)*,
> 106-108)

However it doesn't appear as a description of the so-called robes that clothe the Earth. Rather, this description of the oceans was the product of Keats' creativity as affirmed in an article published in *Sharpe's London Magazine*:

> Many are the poetical descriptions of the foam of the breaking sea,
> such as "Tellus and her briny robes;" (W. E. W., "[The Sea and the Poets](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BUEFAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA19&lpg=RA1-PA19&dq=poetical%20description%20%22briny%20robes%22&source=bl&ots=UPQXbYiEL2&sig=ACfU3U2yQyT5c_FMj6Seo5hezgJb3Hgduw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1n5nvn6PwAhVxs5UCHVVLCx0Q6AEwEXoECBAQAw#v=onepage&q=poetical%20description%20%22briny%20robes%22&f=false)")

A similar affirmation is made in the following [PDF](http://egyanagar.osou.ac.in/slmfiles/MEG-01-BLOCK-07.pdf):

> "Briny robes" in this line refers to the oceans which seem like the
> earth's skirts.

**Some other poetical descriptions:**

Besides speaking of the salty sea, one of the well known descriptions that Homer used was that of the *wine-dark sea*. He also used the idea of a robe clothing the Earth, but rather than a briny robe, this was the golden robe of dawn:

> "Now as the Dawn flung out her golden robe across the earth" (Homer,
> *[The Iliad](https://home.ubalt.edu/ntygfit/ai_01_pursuing_fame/ai_01_tell/iliad08.htm)*, Book VIII)

Ovid portrays the seas encircling the Earth not as a robe, but as an embrace:

> "Nor seas about the shores their arms had thrown" (Ovid,
> *[Metamorphoses](https://ovid.lib.virginia.edu/sources/OviEMet.part1.html)*, Book I)